# In jQuery, I am returning HTML in a JSON result, what do I have to escape?

Tags: jquery, json

In my [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request (using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)) I am returning a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) response.

So json.Html will have a string of HTML I want to append inside a div.

On the server side, do I have to escape the HTML at all?

In my MVC action, I am returning:

```
return Content("{html: ???????}, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to simply return the HTML and use jQuery's `load()`:

```
$('#someDiv').load('servershtml.html');
```

To do it your way though, you would need only to escape double quotes and backslashes.

The [specification](http://json.org) is very readable and short.

Answer (score 7):

You only need to add slashes to quotes and slashes (ala \" and \\) when escaping content to be put into a JSON string.  HTML characters mean nothing inside a JSON string, so they're fine :)

Of course, make sure your string is itself well-formed (X)HTML so that it doesn't explode when inserted into the div.

Comment: what about \a \b \c, there are all ok?

Answer (score 6):

When creating JSON with HTML you have to **escape then double-quote character**, and **also the CLRF character** and it will return HTML fine.

I worked with a pl/sql in oracle procedure that was called from a AJAX request. If you would like, i can post the implementation.

You should test your output at http://www.jsonlint.com/ to see if its valid.

So

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "html_value": "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">test link returnin html code</a>"
}
```

is diffrent from

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "html_value": "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">test link returnin
 html code</a>"
}
```

because of the CLRF character. You should replace that in the server side with `&nbsp`; or `<br/>`.

Hope this helps,
Alex

Answer (score 5):

I will post my experience with PHP. I hope it could helps.

Usually, one use the `json_encode()` function to encode the data, e.g.:

```
json_encode(array('data1' => 'String data with text',
              'data2' => '<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">The Site</a>'));
```

Since `json_encode()` works fine only with UTF-8 strings, I suggest to encode every string in UTF-8 through the function `utf8_encode()`, i.e.

```
json_encode(array(utf8_encode('data1') => utf8_encode('String data with text'),
              utf8_encode('data2') => utf8_encode('<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">The Site</a>')));
```

Moreover, if you are using special chars (like *è* and *à* in Italian words), I suggest to decode the returned json UTF8 encoded HTML. This is particularly useful if you need to use it in an HTML page (e.g. as a result of an AJAX call). To decode through *Javascript*, use:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(html));
```

where `html` is the returned encoded HTML code.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `dataType` [configuration option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) to `'json'` then the object passed to the `complete` event will be that javascript object.  Basically, jQuery will do the work of converting the response content (assuming its properly formatted JSON) to a javascript object.  Example...

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(myJsonObject) {
        alert(myJsonObject.someMember);
    }
}); //$.ajax({
```

If you're wondering how to generate properly formatted JSON from .net, then I would encourage you to explore [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) because it makes generating JSON very, very easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP json_encode does the trick for you:

```
$htmlSnippet = '<a href="#"></foo>';
return json_encode(array("html" => $htmlSnippet));
```

In jQuery you either declare the dataType 'json' (see answer above) or decoding by [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)