# What do I need to escape in my HTML (JSON response)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

My JSON response looks like:

```
{rc: "200", test: "", user: "<div class='sub1'>
                <div class='avatar'>                    
                    <a href='/blah'>blah</a><br />
                    <strong>0</strong>
                </div>
                <div class='sl'>
                    <p>
                        you droppped the ball this time
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class='clear'>
                </div>                        
            </div>"}
```

**Update**

I updated my code to put quotes on the key values, still doesn't work:

```
{"rc": "200", "m" : "", "o": "<div class='s1'>
            <div class='avatar'>                    
                <a href='\/asdf'>asdf<\/a><br \/>
                <strong>0<\/strong>
            <\/div>
            <div class='sl'>
                <p>
                    444444444
                <\/p>
            <\/div>
            <div class='clear'>
            <\/div>                        
        <\/div>"}
```

Comment: nothing in this example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, I am returning HTML in a JSON result, what do I have to escape?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652997/in-jquery-i-am-returning-html-in-a-json-result-what-do-i-have-to-escape)

Comment: test it with http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check which lines are breaking. new line (\n) can be a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate your latest example, and the line breaks are what it flagged.  When they were removed, it validated.

```
{
    "rc": "200",
    "m" : "",
    "o": "<div class='s1'><div class='avatar'><a href='\/asdf'>asdf<\/a><br \/><strong>0<\/strong>      <\/div>    <div class='sl'><p>444444444<\/p><\/div><div class='clear'><\/div><\/div>"
}
```

Comment: How can I escape line breaks programatically?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you won't have to escape anything. But, if the HTML comes with double quotes, you'll have to escape them, obviously.

Comment: Double-quotes and backslash characters. "C:\xyz\" will break things.

Answer (score 1):

You're HTML values are OK, but the keys of the JSON object must be enclosed in quotes.

From the [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> 2.2.  Objects
>
> An object structure is represented
>   as a pair of curly brackets
>   surrounding zero or more name/value
>   pairs (or members).  A name is a
>   string.

and

> 2.5.  Strings
>
> The representation of strings is
>   similar to conventions used in the C
>   family of programming languages.  A
>   string begins and ends with
>   quotation marks.

Also, if you output this JSON object inside the script tags of an HTML page, you must escape the "</" sequence of HTML closing tags, as per [this appendix in the HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.2).

Comment: Ok I updated my code, does that look like it should be working?

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to escape HTML in a javascript string. What exactly are you trying to do/what is the problem? Take a look at the `escape()` function - it might help.

Comment: The badly named escape() function is for URI encoding, and what is needed here is JavaScipt string escaping of the quote (either single or double depending out outer quote, and the backslash).

Comment: There are no double quotes in his example string, and if there were, using escape would convert " to %22 which would avoid any problems with breaking the string. You could then easily use unescape() to bring it back to a readable format.

Comment: But, since JSON is JavaScript object literal notation, the string decoding rules are backed on backslash escaping, not URI escaping.  Why add another layer of custom escaping that has to be done by both sides, when the built in rules will work?

Comment: well given that the OP said there was a problem, but there was no error in the code sample, I was just trying to guess what might be the problem.

Comment: You do need to escape HTML in JS strings in an HTML file. In other words, if you have an HTML file with a <script> tag containing a JS string which contains HTML, it needs to be escaped.