# Cannot identify file format

Tags: html

First of all, sorry for not formatting this properly.

Does anybody have an idea about which file format this is? 
Somehow it looks like escaped HTML...

```
[{"cross_rate_1":{"1":" <\/span>EUR\/USD<\/span><\/td><\/nobr>1.1143<\/td>1.1144<\/td>1.1201<\/td>1.1207<\/td>1.1132<\/td>-0.0058<\/td>-0.51%<\/td>","2":" <\/span>GBP\/USD<\/span><\/td><\/nobr>1.5597<\/td>1.5599<\/td>1.5447<\/td>1.5598<\/td>1.5394<\/td>+0.0142<\/td>+0.92%<\/td>","3":" <\/span>USD\/JPY<\/span><\/td><\/nobr>120.06<\/td>120.08<\/td>119.69<\/td>120.10<\/td>
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like (a fragment of) [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) returning HTML

Take a look at [In jQuery, I am returning HTML in a JSON result, what do I have to escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652997/in-jquery-i-am-returning-html-in-a-json-result-what-do-i-have-to-escape)